# ajax is concept and the implementation

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser

I hear that AJAX is a concept and all the browsers implemented this concept.

Can anyone point out some links related to this.

1. Where the ajax engine runs and how browser is able to identify ajax  request and respond generically?
2. Is AJAX  JavaScript specific?
3. By default any browser will support AJAX?
4. Who created AJAX RFC and is this part of HTML RFC?

Comment: Well... look here https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ajax/info

Comment: https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

Comment: Feels like 2005 again. ;)

Answer (score 2):

> I hear that AJAX is a concept

It's (weakly defined) jargon for "Make an HTTP request from browser-side JavaScript without leaving the page".

> and all the browsers implemented this concept.

No.

You'd be hard pressed to find a browser which supported JS which didn't allow you to perform Ajax, but Ajax isn't a specific technology, so there isn't explicit support for it.

Browsers support things like `XMLHttpRequest`, and the ability to dynamically generate `script` elements with `src` attributes. These let you perform Ajax.

> Where the ajax engine runs and how browser is able to identify ajax request and respond generically.

There's no such thing as an Ajax engine. See my previous point.

> Also AJAX is JavaScript specific?

By definition, yes.

> By default any browser will support AJAX?

No. Lynx doesn't support JS at all, for example.

> Who created AJAX RFC

There's no such thing. Again, see previous comment about Ajax being a thing you can do with various different technologies. Those technologies have specifications, Ajax does not.

> and is this part of HTML RFC ?

No. HTML hasn't been defined via a RFC since before JavaScript existed.

The latest HTML specification goes some way to defining some of the technologies involved, but they are largely the purview of separate specifications (such as the DOM and XMLHttpRequest recommendations).